# why these functionalities i am missing,thought i have the correct spring 3.0 jar

Tags: spring, maven-2

I am learning spring by reference documentation of 3.0

and i wanted to test the below functionality but these are not available..

> 1. @PostConstruct
> 2. context.registershutdownhook

P.S.: I am using jdk 5.0

when i type these in my eclipse,I am getting an error that these are not avaialble..

Below is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.SpringExample</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringExample</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `@javax.annotation.PostConstruct` is not shipped with Spring, although Spring supports it if it finds it on the classpath. `@PostConstruct` can be found in Java6, but not in Java5. You can also find it in some EJB3 downloads.
2. `registerShutdownHook()` is a method on `ConfigurableApplicationContext`, which is a subtype of `ApplicationContext`.

Comment: 1) To resolve the issue i need to have JDK 6.0
2) To get registerShutdownHook() in my code,What should i add in pom.xml -- I tried googling about this but could not get much info..

Thanks for ur time & answers

Comment: @javanerd: 1) Yes, 2) This isn't a POM problem, you're just looking at the wrong interface. You need to look at `ConfigurableApplicationContext`, not `ApplicationContext`.